# Do I need Korea Visa when transit at Incheon Airport, as an Indonesian citizen?

Tags: south-korea, transit-visas, indonesian-citizens, icn

I'm travelling from London (UK) to Jakarta and using 2 different airlines (2 separate tickets - non connecting flight), from London to Incheon using Asiana (1 ticket), and from Incheon to Jakarta using SQ/Singapore airlines (1 ticket) and have to layover at Incheon about 8 hours. Do I need a Korea visa if I have to transfer/change the airlines? Or can I change airlines without visa? I'm an Indonesia passport holder

Comment: Have you checked luggage?

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I fly through Incheon Airport from the US to China and Hong Kong, I never need to go through customs/immigration. I usually stay within the airport and do a transfer, which does not require a visa.

If you exit the airport, then you will need to go through customs/immigration. And Indonesian passport holders will need a visa to visit Korea (exit the airport).

Comment: If the two flights are on seperate tickets, then the OP will probably need to collect and recheck baggage landside. Which will mean passing through Korean immigration.

Comment: Some countries require certain people to have a visa even if they remain airside, eg [the UK's Direct Airside Transit Visa](https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa/direct-airside-transit-visa), so simply remaining airside isn't always enough to avoid visa requirements